# How can I apply atomic locks to all of my routes in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, session, blocking

I have a single page application which is computing multiple AJAX requests, via `axios`. Occasionally, I run into a scenario where both requests run async at the same time and attempt to write to the session which causes a `419` response code where the `CSRF` token is dropped in the response forcing me to have to logout the user.

After debugging this, I come across [session blocking](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#session-blocking) which makes use of atomic locks.

My session provider is the database and I have the standard Schema that ships with Laravel for this capability. Currently, I must specify this on my routes like so:

```
Route::any('/example', [SomeController::class, 'someFunction')->block();
```

However, I have a mass amount of routes and since the application is SPA, is there a way to make this happen by default at service provider level?

It is not possible to `Route::group(...)->block()` which is what I did originally try.

Comment: You've linked a screenshot in your question which contains a `localhost:8000` reference. Please fix the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieving this is a bit of a pain. But before I present a solution, a short analysis:

The `Route::block($lockSeconds = 10, $waitSeconds = 10)` method internally sets the attributes `lockSeconds` and `waitSeconds` on the Route. If these two attributes are added to a group definition, they are actually passed to the route, but unfortunately under the sub key `action`:

```
Route::group(['lockSeconds' => 10, 'waitSeconds' => 10, 'prefix' => 'api/spa'], function () {
    Route::get('foo', fn () => response()->json(['result' => 'ok']));
});

// Dump of the route
"api/spa/foo" => Illuminate\Routing\Route {#217 ▼
  +uri: "api/spa/foo"
  +methods: array:2 [▶]
  +action: array:5 [▼
    "middleware" => array:1 [▶]
    "uses" => Closure() {#216 ▶}
    "namespace" => null
    "prefix" => ""
    "where" => [],
    "lockSeconds" => 10,             <-- we got the setting here
    "waitSeconds" => 10              <--
  ]
  +isFallback: false
  +controller: null
  +defaults: []
  +wheres: []
  +parameters: null
  +parameterNames: null
  #originalParameters: null
  #withTrashedBindings: false
  #lockSeconds: null                 <-- we want the setting here though
  #waitSeconds: null                 <--
  +computedMiddleware: null
  +compiled: null
  #router: Illuminate\Routing\Router {#25 ▶}
  #container: Illuminate\Foundation\Application {#3 ▶}
  #bindingFields: []
}
```

That leaves us with the situation that defining the two attributes during route registration is not possible. But fortunately, we can also manipulate routes after they've been added to the route collection:

```
foreach (Route::getRoutes() as $route) {
    $route->block();
}
```

This code is best placed at the bottom of your `routes/web.php` or at the end of the `map()` method in your `RouteServiceProvider`. You also may want to filter your routes when doing this and only update routes starting with a given prefix:

```
foreach (Route::getRoutes() as $route) {
    if (str_starts_with($route->uri(), 'api/spa')) {
        $route->block();
    }
}
```

Comment: Really did not think to just loop over the routes, hopefully atomic locking is the solution but your detailed answer is more than perfect to employing a practical solution to attempt to fix it. Thank-you!

Comment: @Jaquarh I found the request quite interesting, so I proposed a new `afterRegisterCallback` for route groups in a [PR](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/42882).

Comment: Nice job! I spent a while looking at the `group` method for this and then ultimately decided the service provider was the next port of call. It didn't think to simply loop the collection but your PR is useful when you want to manipulate the collection of a specific group rather than, as you mentioned, specially when you only want to apply it to specific middleware or URI's. Great job, well earned and I'm glad my question sparked interest for you!

Comment: Sometimes things seem a lot easier retrospectively. Happens to the best!

Comment: The PR has been declined though (kinda expected it, to be honest).

Comment: Strange, probably  would be a nice package. I feel like manipulating the route at group level is a powerful feature.

Comment: It would be hard to implement as package due to all the overrides required. Maybe when I'm bored one day... 